# Specman e: How to constrain distribution of values inside list of list?

Tags: constraints, specman, e

I have `my_list` (list of structs) that defined this way:

```
struct my_struct {
    comparator[2] : list of int;
    something_else[2] : list of uint;
};

my_list[10] : list of my_struct;
```

I need to constrain distribution of values of comparator[0] and comparator[1] (same distribution for both), something like this:

```
my_list[10] : list of my_struct;
keep soft for each (elem) in my_list {
   soft elem.comparator[0] select {
      30: [-1000 .. -50]; -- Big negative values
      40: [-49 ..49]; -- Medium values
      30: [50..1000]; -- Big positive values           
    };
    // Same for elem.comparator[1]
 };
```

The compilation error I get:

```
*** Error: Unrecognized exp
    [Unrecognized expression 'elem.comparator[0] select {30:
[-1000..-50];40: [-49..49];30: [50..1000];}']
                at line
...
       soft elem.comparator[0] select {
```

How to constrain distribution of values that resides inside list of list?
Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `soft` in there twice, though that isn't the problem. You forgot to put a `==` before `select`. I'd write it like this:

```
  keep for each (elem) in my_list {
    soft elem.comparator[0] == select {
      30: [-1000 .. -50]; -- Big negative values
      40: [-49 ..49]; -- Medium values
      30: [50..1000]; -- Big positive values           
    };
    // Same for elem.comparator[1]
  };
```

Alternatively you can do `keep soft for each ...`, which in your case is probably cleaner. You can even leave both `soft`s in there, though it looks a bit ugly, IMO.